# Logical operator fails after a computation

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

```js
var sub_response_type = {"survey_question":["Test lable"],"responseTypeText":"Exit label","select_param_type":[">","<"],"questions_id":["7","8"],"select_param_value":["12","34"],"radio_type":["&&"]};

    var order = ['questions_id', 'select_param_type', 'select_param_value', 'radio_type'];
    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    
    do result.push(...order.map(k => sub_response_type[k][i]));
    while (sub_response_type.radio_type[i++])

    result = result.join(' ');
    console.log("results: ", result);
    
    if (result) {
        console.log("True");
    }else{
        console.log("False");
    }
```

I would like to use the `result` above that is in the format `7 > 12 && 8 < 34` to execute it in the if statement for comparison following.

In this case, it should output false as `7 > 12 && 8 < 34` this executes to false using the Logical operators.

For some reason it outputs true.

What am I missing, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is the literal string `' 7 > 12 && 8 < 34 '`, and non-empty strings are truthy, so you get `true`.

If you want to evaluate it as a Javascript expression, first remove all characters which could result in arbitrary code execution by whitelisting, say, numbers and the operators you want to permit, remove all other characters, and then `eval` it:

```js
var sub_response_type = {
  "survey_question": ["Test lable"],
  "responseTypeText": "Exit label",
  "select_param_type": [">", "<"],
  "questions_id": ["7", "8"],
  "select_param_value": ["12", "34"],
  "radio_type": ["&&"]
};

var order = ['questions_id', 'select_param_type', 'select_param_value', 'radio_type'];
var result = [];
var i = 0;

do result.push(...order.map(k => sub_response_type[k][i]));
while (sub_response_type.radio_type[i++]);

const origStr = result.join(' ');
const safeStr = origStr.replace(/[^\d&>< ]+/g, '');
console.log(safeStr);
console.log(eval(safeStr));
```

(If you're absolutely certain that the input is from a trustworthy source, you don't *need* to do the replacement, but it's probably a good idea to do anyway)